# how does telerik mvc grid autogernerate columns work?

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

i'm using telerik mvc grid (latest open source edition) , it does **NOT** work with my viewmodel when

using autogenerate columns(.Columns(c=>c.AutoGenerate(true)) feature  , but

.Columns(c=>c.Bound("Id") works , i searched on telerik help  but ...

Comment: ... but what? If you are setting columns then the autogenerate won't work. AutoGenerate will iterate over all of your object properties and create a column for each one. Just create a ViewModel with the necessary properties, and autogenerate will take care of the rest.

Comment: sorry , i missed out a word 'not";